# SetTimer function in a dll file

Tags: c++, plugins, dll

I'm writing a plugin for the musicplayer named MusicBee.
The plugin is for the Logitech G keyboards LCD.
Now I will look at buttons activity every 30ms so everyting is fast when pressing on it.
I will use the setTimer function of windows.h but I can't get it to work in my dll file.
Can someone help me with this little problem??

The code I have is (TimerProc function is a static function):

```
Logitech * Logitech::LogitechObject;

Logitech::Logitech():   stopthread(false), firstTime(true), position(0), duration(0)
{
    LogitechObject = this;

    SetTimer(NULL, 1, 30, &Logitech::TimerProc);
}

Logitech::~Logitech()
{
    stopthread = true;
    this->state = StatePlay::Undefined;
    timerThread.detach();
}

VOID CALLBACK Logitech::TimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent,  DWORD dwTime)
{
    LogitechObject->time = 0;
    LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, static_cast<FLOAT>(100));
    LogitechObject->m_lcd.Update();

    SetTimer(NULL, 1, 30, &Logitech::TimerProc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order SetTimer to work the application should run "message pump" loop ( `GetMessage()`/`DispatchMessage()` ). Without it WM_TIMER message will not be delivered and so  your TimerProc will not be invoked.

Use `CreateTimerQueueTimer()` instead.

Comment: Now I changed my settimer to CreateTimerQueueTimer(NULL,NULL,&Logitech::TimerProc,this,0,1250,WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT); and now it crashes every time I start it. What can it be?